# Translating from ASIHTTPRequest to AFNetworking , on iOS

Tags: ios, asihttprequest, afnetworking

What i want to do is post a json file to my server. I finally did that using ASIHTTPRequest and my code is :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://foo.foo.foo"];
            ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
            [request setRequestMethod:@"PUT"];

            [request addRequestHeader:@"Authorization" value:@"Basic dslfkdsfdsflsdkfslkgflksflksdlfkg"]; 
            [request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json; charset=utf-8"];


            [request appendPostData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 
            [request startSynchronous];

            NSLog(@"%@", [request responseString]);
```

What i need now is the exact above code translated to AFNetworking. Any ideas??
Thank you for reading my post :)

Answer (score 3):

```
AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://foo.foo.foo"]];
client.parameterEncoding = AFJSONParameterEncoding;
[client registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestionOperation class]];
[client setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:... password:...];
[client putPath:@"/path/to/resource" parameters:(_your JSON object as a dictionary_) 
            success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
              NSLog(@"%@", [request responseString]);
          } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
              NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
          }];
```